# Why can't i construct a vector by passing temporary input iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, istream-iterator

I often used istream_iterator copy standard input to a vector like this:

```
copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(vec));
```

it works.

Today when i construct a vector by this:

```
vector<int> vec(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>());
copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

it just can not compile!

But if i construct it like this:

```
istream_iterator<int> beg(cin), end;
vector<int> vec(beg, end); 
copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

it works.

Why? Can not i use temporary variables to construct a vector? If it does, but why could i do it when i use std::copy?

ps: I compiled it under vs2005 and i used the following head files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a function declaration:

```
vector<int> vec(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>());
```

It's a function named `vec`, that returns a `vector<int>` by value and takes two parameters: an `istream_iterator<int>` with a formal parameter name of `cin`, and a function with no formal parameter name that returns an `istream_iterator<int>`, and takes no parameters.

**Why?**

Basically, in C++(and C), if a piece of code can be interpreted as a declaration, it will be.

According to N3936::6.8.1 [stmt.ambig]:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements
>   and declarations: An expressionstatement with a function-style
>   explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be
>   indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts
>   with a (. In those cases the statement is a declaration. [ Note: To
>   disambiguate, the whole statement might have to be examined to
>   determine if it is an expression-statement or a declaration. This
>   disambiguates many examples. [ Example: assuming T is a
>   simple-type-specifier (7.1.6),
>
> T(a)->m = 7;      // expression-statement
>   T(a)++;           // expression-statement
>   T(a,5) << c;      // expression-statement
>
> T(*d)(int);       // declaration
>   T(e)[5];          // declaration
>   T(f) = { 1, 2 };  //declaration
>   T(*g)(double(3)); // declaration
>
> In the last example
>   above, g, which is a pointer to T, is initialized to double(3). This
>   is of course ill-formed for semantic reasons, but that does not affect
>   the syntactic analysis. —end example ]

**How to fix it**

All we need is something that makes it impossible for the compiler to treat the code as a function declaration.

1. Adding the extra parentheses around the parameters makes it clear to the
   compiler that what we intend to be constructor parameter names can't be parameter declarations.

   `vector<int> vec((istream_iterator<int>(cin)), istream_iterator<int>());`
2. As your solution showed, using named variables as constructor parameters.